# change opacity of clicked li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change opacity of clicked li element, all the li elements have the same class

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/apXfE/1/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="someclass" selectedTeamId="1">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="someclass" selectedTeamId="2">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="someclass" selectedTeamId="3">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="someclass"selectedTeamId="4">test</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="someclass"selectedTeamId="5">test</a></li>
</ul>



 $(".someclass:not('.removeTeamSelect')").live("click", function () {
    var teamId = $(this).attr("selectedTeamId");


    $(".someclass").each(function () {
tempId=$(this).attr("selectedTeamId");
        alert(tempId+"#"+teamId);
        if (tempId == teamId) {

            $(this).css({ "opacity": "1" });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({"opacity":"0.1"});
        }
    });

});
```

What am i missing?

Comment: please provide the HTML code. `.live()` method is deprecated, you `teamId` variable does not change across the callback function

Comment: maybe because you are alerting same variable twice?

Comment: where is this tempid come from? - if (tempId == teamId) -

Comment: yeah added the html and jsfiddle links!!

Comment: i dono why the question got a down vote !! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it more like this:

```
$('ul').on('click', ".horizontalTeams:not('.removeTeamSelect')", function() {
    $(".horizontalTeams").each(function () {
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0.1"});
    });
    $(this).css({"opacity":"1"});

});
```

As I assume from your code, you change opacity of clicked element to 1 and all others to 0.1? This code should do exactly that.

You should use **on** instead of **live**, **live** is deprecated, **on** does the same job.

And you should use event delegation(see the code) as @jogesh_pi mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Thank you it worked, after adding a close bracket for $().each :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/apXfE/
this is just an example how you should implement it into your codes:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="someclass">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="someclass notthis">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="someclass">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="someclass">test</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="someclass notthis">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.someclass:not(".notthis")', function(){
    alert('w');
});
```